# How to add a column to spark dataframe with custom _id field of type Mongo ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load data from Elasticsearch to Mongo DB. I want to retain the same _id value that is present in elasticsearch while writing to Mongo as well. I'm able to do it, but the _id field is of type String in Elastic search and I would like to push it into Mongo DB after coverting it to Mongo ObjectId datatype.

The data from elasticsearch is loaded into a dataframe. I'm using spark scala for doing the same. Any help to achieve this?

I have tried it this way modifying the dataframe, but it throws up error,

```
    df("_id") = new ObjectId(df("_id"))
```

It doesn't work this way.

```
    val df = spark.read
                  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                  .option("query", esQuery)
                  .option("pushdown", true)
                  .option("scroll.size", Config.ES_SCROLL_SIZE)
                  .load(Config.ES_RESOURCE)
                  .withColumn("_id", $"_metadata".getItem("_id"))
                  .drop("_metadata")

    df("_id") = new ObjectId(df("_id"))
```

I want to load dataframe into mongo DB with _id field as Mongo ObjectId datatype rather than String datatype.

```
    Present:  _id : "123456ABCD" 
    Expected: _id : ObjectId(123456ABCD)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
.withColumn("date", typedLit(new ObjectId($"_metadata".getItem("_id"))))
```

Comment: org.bson.types.ObjectId
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
      .withColumn("_id", typedLit(new ObjectId($"_metadata".getItem("_id"))))

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val toObjectId = udf[ObjectId,String](new ObjectId(_))
      .withColumn("date", toObjectId($"_metadata".getItem("_id")))` try this

Comment: I am trying this approach and I am getting the following error: 'UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type com.mongodb.spark.sql.fieldTypes.api.java.ObjectId is not supported'. I don't know if it is because UDF does not support the ObjectId data type or why.. any idea?